# JAX-RS/Restfull - API and session managment

Tags: session, rest, jax-rs, session-cookies, restful-architecture

Although jax rs rest services force the creation of a new resource instance  per request would it be a bad idea/bad practice to hold session information for a limited amount of time for my rest web service ?

Comment: They do? I thought that was just a deployment option.

Comment: actually you are right they can either be deployed as singletons or by forcing the creation of new resource instance per request... However the question still remains the same, should I hold session info for rest services ?